# JNDI: Naming Service vs Directory Service

Tags: java, jndi, directoryservices

As far as Java/JNDI verbiage goes, are "*directory services*" just more complex versions of "*naming services*"?

If you read the JNDI [glossary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/concepts/glossary.html), it basically defines these two as follows:

- `naming service` - An API that allows you to perform operations on different *contexts*
- `context` - Sounds an awful lot like a `HashMap`
- `directory service` - An API that allows you to perform operations on *directory objects*
- `directory object` - an object that is in a directory....(?!?!)

So, unless I am mistaken, it sounds like both types of services allow CRUD-like operations on different types of objects, either `contexts` (in the case of a naming service) or `directory objects` (in the case of directory services).

So my question is: whats the difference?!? Aren't both of these context/directory object types really just hashmaps/hashtables under the hood?

I'm choking on these differences because I'm trying to get an understanding of when something is a naming service, and when it is a directory service, and these definitions are difficult for me to gauge.

Comment: +1 because I hate circular definitions:  _directory:A connected set of directory objects. directory object:An object that is in the directory_. Argh!

Comment: From here (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/concepts/directory.html): `directory service = naming service + objects containing attributes`

Answer (score 2):

> Aren't both of these context/directory object types really just
>   hashmaps/hashtables under the hood?

No, they are almost certainly database tables under the hood, and they have all kinds of semantics such as attribute lists, the ability to create child contexts, etc, that hashmaps/hashtables don't have.

Comment: Thanks EJP, but then what is their *difference*?! Its fine if they are both database tables (and not hashmaps), but why distinguish between the two? That was at the root of my question.

Comment: @AdamTannon A naming service is a server, e.g. LDAP, or the RMI Registry. A Context is an object in a naming service. A directory service is a directory-structured naming service. A directory object is a directory-structured Context, i.e. a DirContext. The RMI Registry isn't a directory service and it doesn't have directory contexts. LDAP is, and does.

Comment: Thanks EJP - last question (I'm not trying to be difficult here, I'm just missing some fundamental principles here): then what is the difference between a "directory-structured service" and a "service"; between a "directory-structured context" and a "context"? Is it just that a "directory" implies the object/context can have other values/attributes (besides its name) associated with it?

Comment: @Adam Tannon 'Directory' implies hierarchy and attributes. For example, DirContext has subcontexts and attributes; Context doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think directory service is referenced in this acronym only to recall naming services with **directory** in the acronym, like LDAP.

LDAP, DNS and so on are naming services, because *directory services* and *naming services* are synonyms.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service):

> In software engineering, a directory is a map between names and values.

Note that in wikipedia, [Name Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_service) redirects to the same article.